# Extract lowest Levels from nested List

Tags: python, list, nested

I got an irregular multiple nested list like this:

```
[[[[-109.57138824416198, 33.88133239733474],
   [-109.57106780956572, 33.88137054433046],
   [-109.57102203399924, 33.88110733049322],
   [-109.57134246861581, 33.881069183483866],
   [-109.57138824416198, 33.88133239733474]]],
 [[[-109.53874206509292, 34.03271865867248],
   [-109.5387878420307, 34.03298568681619],
   [-109.53845977734206, 34.0330238343362],
   [-109.538414001351, 34.032756805190026],
   [-109.53874206509292, 34.03271865867248]]],
 [[[-109.53874206509292, 34.03271865867248],
   [-109.53869628939387, 34.032451629408015],
   [-109.53864288285274, 34.03218841550364],
...
```

So you can not tell how deep it can get or on which level the entries are. But on the lowest level there are always two entries (Longitude and Latitude) For a boundingbox I need Min- and Max-Values for Lon and Lat separatly. My idea was two get rid of all the sublevel-lists to have only tuples left to deal with.

Any ideas for a solution?

Comment: Please show what you've tried.

Comment: They are not tuples.

Comment: I just had no clue what to do, other questions were mostly related to a specific, known structure...

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
lst = [
    [
        [
            [-109.57138824416198, 33.88133239733474],
            [-109.57106780956572, 33.88137054433046],
            [-109.57102203399924, 33.88110733049322],
            [-109.57134246861581, 33.881069183483866],
            [-109.57138824416198, 33.88133239733474],
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            [-109.53874206509292, 34.03271865867248],
            [-109.5387878420307, 34.03298568681619],
            [-109.53845977734206, 34.0330238343362],
            [-109.538414001351, 34.032756805190026],
            [-109.53874206509292, 34.03271865867248],
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            [-109.53874206509292, 34.03271865867248],
            [-109.53869628939387, 34.032451629408015],
            [-109.53864288285274, 34.03218841550364],
        ]
    ],
]


def flatten(lst):
    if isinstance(lst, list):
        if isinstance(lst[0], list):
            for v in lst:
                yield from flatten(v)
        else:
            yield lst


out = list(flatten(lst))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    [-109.57138824416198, 33.88133239733474],
    [-109.57106780956572, 33.88137054433046],
    [-109.57102203399924, 33.88110733049322],
    [-109.57134246861581, 33.881069183483866],
    [-109.57138824416198, 33.88133239733474],
    [-109.53874206509292, 34.03271865867248],
    [-109.5387878420307, 34.03298568681619],
    [-109.53845977734206, 34.0330238343362],
    [-109.538414001351, 34.032756805190026],
    [-109.53874206509292, 34.03271865867248],
    [-109.53874206509292, 34.03271865867248],
    [-109.53869628939387, 34.032451629408015],
    [-109.53864288285274, 34.03218841550364],
]
```

Comment: Wow this looks nice, even though I am not able to confirm correctness. Results are plausible.